# jQuery Drag with mouse and move with key then print x-y co-ordinates?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, keyboard-events

I am trying to make an element draggable, movable by key press and then print the x-y co-ordinates to an input box. The element moves, and is draggable, but does not print the co-ordinates when using the keyboard to move it.

This is part of the code I am using.

```
$('.dragThis').draggable({
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = Math.round(offset.left);
        var yPos = Math.round(offset.top);
        $("#x").val(xPos);
        $('#y').val(yPos);
    }
});

var $div = $('.dragThis');
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
    $div.css('top', $div.offset().top - 1);
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = Math.round(offset.left);
    var yPos = Math.round(offset.top);
    $("#x").val(xPos);
    $('#y').val(yPos);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/1154/

Related: I would also like to do a shift+arrow movement for +10 instead of +1 but alas it is also not working.

Thanks